# Auto close application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm new to this site and VB, so please keep that in mind.

I have a program which basically connects to our database and updates it, but what I want is after this code:

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As system.EventArgs) Handels Button1.Click
        If Retry = 0 then
            End
        Else
            TextBox3.Textt = ""
            Button1.text = "Ok"
            Button1.enabled = False
            Me.refresh()

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

            Me.Form1_Load(Me, e)

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

            Me.Refresh()
            System.Windows.Form.Application.DoEvent()
        End If
    End Sub
End Clas
```

This form/App to close (can be closed before this part as it just tells me everything went well but still if you click ok will retry) so I don't have to close it every time I run this app to update and then annoyingly stay awake as it won't let me study the code nor let me change anything until this app is closed. sometime it takes so long that i even forget i have this app running.

I can provide more info if tell me what otherwise I don't know much about VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Me.Close()` it will close the form when executed.

Or `Application.Exit()` you can check [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @RokieHud JUST put `Application.Exit()` or `Me.Close()` where you want to exit your app

Comment: Usually accept answer will be nice or at least thumbs up for @AliTheOne but still....i am happy that it worked.